# Bootstrap Modal Form won't close

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table populated with data where each row has an edit button. Upon edit, a bootstrap modal popup form appears, with the table row data that is now editable. This popup form has a submit button, and a close button. The close button works as expected (closed the modal popup), and the submit button does update my data, but will not close the form.

So in short, I have the modal popup showing up correctly, and the submit button on the popup actually works, but I cannot get the form to then close after the data has been updated.

Here are the relevant parts...

**index.html.erb**

```
<tbody class="majors-index">
    <!-- This renders my table with all the data and edit buttons -->
    <%= render 'index' %>
</tbody>
....
....
<div class="modal" id="major-modal">
</div>
....
```

**_index.html.erb**

```
....
<!-- This opens the modal dialogue -->
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_major_path(m), remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary", data: {toggle: 'modal', target: "#major-modal"} %>
....
```

**edit.js.erb**

```
// display the modal form
$("#major-modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "majors/edit") %>")
$("#major-modal").modal("toggle")
```

**_edit.html.erb**

```
<!-- #modal-without-animation -->
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4><%= "Editing #{@major.name}" %></h4>
    </div>
    <%= render "form"%>
  </div>
</div>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @major, remote: true, html: {class: "form-horizontal", style: "display-inline;"} do |f| %>
    <div class="modal-body">
    ....
    ....
    <%= f.submit "Modify", class: "btn btn-primary", id: "btnSubmit" %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", "#", class: "btn", data: {dismiss: "modal"} %>
    ....
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Now, upon hitting submit, the first thing that gets called is my update.js.erb, which should be closing my modal form.

**update.js.erb**

```
$("#major-modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "majors/edit") %>")
$("#major-modal").modal("toggle")
```

But for whatever reason, the modal form will not close. I have tried switching the "toggle" to "hide", but that also has no effect. I know for a fact the update.js.erb is getting called, because if I just stick an alert in there, it gets fired.

What am I doing wrong? Why won't the modal form close?

UPDATE:

Here is my controller...

```
def update
    @majors = Major.all
    @major = Major.find(params[:id])
    @major.update_attributes(major_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Comment: So, where is the code that tells the modal to hide on form submit?  There should be a condition that on submit, $("#major-modal").modal("hide");

Comment: @user3743250 it is in the `update.js.erb` file. I am using "toggle", which is supposed to hide it if the form is currently open. Even when I explicitly say "hide", I still have no success.

Comment: $('#major-modal').modal('hide'); - This code is directly from one of my projects and it works perfectly.  Are you remembering to put the ";" at the end?

Comment: Shouldn't matter in js.erb file, but even with the semi-colon, the modal will still not close.

Comment: Is the modal created dynamically via jquery?  Or is it pre-rendered in html and then hidden via css?

Comment: It is rendered via ajax. $("#major-modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "majors/edit") %>")
$("#major-modal").modal("toggle"). Check above, I have it in my post.

Comment: Why are edit.js.erb and update.js.erb the exact same code?

Answer (score 0):

ok, so after the page is rendered.  When adding a new element dynamically it doesn't necessarily get added to the DOM for easy jquery selection.  It cannot close an element that doesn't exist.

You can solve this with a delegate event:

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('submit', '#major-modal', function() {
    $(this).modal('hide');
});
```

this is assuming you are putting it into a document ready clause, like so:

```
$(document).ready(
$('#btnSubmit').on('submit', '#major-modal', function () {
    $(this).modal('hide');
}));
```

Comment: In the context of my current files, where would I put this?

Comment: So, you won't need to call this.  Because this is a listening event waiting for you to hit the submit button.  You shouldn't need your update.js.erb file anymore.  Just put the above code in any javascript file that is featured in your project.

Comment: Do I have to change my modal form at all? Like, I still need the `remote: true` syntax, right? I have added the javascript in the document.ready section on page, but it still doesn't ever seem to get fired. I am verifying this with Firebug in Firefox. Or is there something else I have to do in my update in the controller?

Comment: I think the problem is that my btnSubmit is technically on a different page than the major-modal div. For example, if I view page source, the form doesn't show up, since it is in the modal, while the div is on my main index page.

Comment: I am afraid I am not familiar with ruby on rails.  I can only help you as far as html, css and jquery are concerned.  Did you remove the code that was originally calling the update.js.erb?  Disable that file and any calls to it because it might be conflicting with the listener event.